# pass an argument as an Object._property to a callback function on onClick gives error (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass an item's id to a callback function in React to handle an action on that item when the button is clicked as following

```
     <button onClick={(item._id) => handleDelete(item._id)}>
           <i className='far fa-trash-alt'></i>
     </button>
```

but I get this error `JSX expression must have one parent element`. However, if I try

```
     <button onClick={(_id) => handleDelete(_id)}>
           <i className='far fa-trash-alt'></i>
     </button>
```

it doesn't object. Why does it object on the first syntax, and is there a way around it?

Comment: The error you're getting and the solution you're trying look different. Can you post the entire `return()` block here?

Comment: I logged the passed argument, and it seems it takes it as the synthetic event regardless of the name, given it's valid. So, I had just to do `<button onClick={() => handleDelete(item._id)}>`

Comment: Yes, the callback passed to `onClick` will be called with an event object as the first argument, of course regardless of the parameter name you accept.